# Cannot resolve symbol RoomDatabase

Tags: android, dependencies, android-room

I want to try out Room Persistence library, but after adding and downloading it with gradle, I can find most classes, except:

```java
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;

import com.doors.geopoly.dal.entities.User;

@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)

public abstract class GeoDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

Every room library class is present, except RoomDatabase will be red in the IDE stating that it can't resolve that symbol.

Why?

Here's my gradle config:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"

        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
        annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I had the same error as the OP, with no suggestion offered.

To fix, I had to manually create the import:

```
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you separated layers like [Clean Architecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture).

if we suppose that you use a separated module for wrapping all of db transactions and so on that named `db_module`

You should note that `Room` is an Android Library that are `lifecycleAware` and depend on Android platform, so you must define your `db_module` - that contain Room - as an Android library.

so it's just using

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
```

instead of

```
apply plugin: "java"
```

this changes your java module to a android module that contain Android OS properties.